# Excel - Line Chart showing data from 2 tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have 2 tables. One has entries per month. Second has entries per day. I want both the table values to be plotted on single line chart according to appropriate dates. How can that be done?

Table 1:

```
Date        NAV
01-07-16    762.4133
01-08-16    795.9444
```

Table 2:

```
Date        NAV
01-01-13    312.2387
02-01-13    312.7387
03-01-13    311.1387
.
.
.
16-03-19    830.5179
```

Comment: Looking at your data (different years and sample months do not overlap) I surmise you need two x-axises: [Add or remove a secondary axis in a chart in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-remove-a-secondary-axis-in-a-chart-in-excel-91da1e2f-5db1-41e9-8908-e1a2e14dd5a9) (excel line chart multiple axis).

Comment: @TedD. Table 1 will have dates out of Table 2.

Comment: I have written a tutorial about this very topic, [Multiple Time Series in an Excel Chart](https://peltiertech.com/multiple-time-series-excel-chart/).

Answer (score 2):

#### Multi Line Chart, where each data set includes its own x-axis values

> 1. Select one set of data.

[image]

> 2. **Insert** a **Scatter Chart** with straight lines.

[image]

> 3. Select the next set of Data.

[image]

> 4. Copy the selection (eg <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>).
>
> *With the running ants around the second set of Data,*
>
> 5. Select the Chart.

[image]

> 6. Paste Special (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> may not work and there does not appear to be a right click - context sensitive menu - for this action)
>
> - OR - Use the Expanded Paste Menu (see this image's: #2 - down arrow).

[image]

> 7. Use the Excel chosen defaults if they are correct, **click <kbd>OK</kbd>**

[image]
Correct Configuration - If the new data is outside the existing chart, Excel may not have this correct configuration.

**Finished Chart**

[image]

> 8. Add labels ...

**Note,** this ***does not*** seem to work with **Line Charts**, that is why these directions use a **Scatter Chart** with straight lines.